# Can I increase the volume of the end-of-call beep?

Tags: settings, audio, calls

According to this [article](https://www.slashgear.com/google-softening-android-end-call-tone-beep-30556523/amp/), Google softened the end-of-call beep to an almost inaudible level following customer feedback. I happened to like the beep because it made it easy to know if a call had been dropped when the signal was rubbish. Is there a way to bring it back? (I know it’s still there, but, as I said, it’s almost inaudible, even when the call volume is set to max. I’d like to raise the beep volume.)

Thanks for any help.